# Using a catch all route in Web Api2 along with exceptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a catch all route that I use to forward  requests to another restful services like so:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/casemanager/{*url}")]    
public class CaseManagerController : ApiController {
```

This works great, I have Get/Delete/Put/Update functions that receive the url parameter and I forward those on.

I would however like to introduce a few exceptions, that I do not forward along to another service.  For instance I'd like to be able to add a method to the class like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/casemanager/exception")]    
public string SomethingElse()
{
    return "Something Else";
}
```

I have tried the above, and I have tried setting the Order property on the routes to give the exception precedence, but it appears to always hit the catch all.  Is there a nice way to accomplish this?